# Reusing code within a loop without using functions

Tags: c#, loops, refactoring, code-duplication

I have the following code which scans a 2D array **row by row**

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
    {
        // Code here that scans a 2D array using i & j as the indices
    }
}
```

This is followed by another set of loops which scan the same array **column by column**

```
for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        // Code that is a near duplicate of the code in the previous set of loops
    }
}
```

The code inside the above 2 sets of loops are nearly identical. Is there any way I can remove the duplication? I would prefer not to move the code into a separate function as this code is going to be run quite often on a pretty huge array, and AFAIK there isn't a way to force inlining in C#.

Comment: What's wrong with calling a function inside a loop?

Comment: You can try to force inlining, is not guaranteed to be inlined but usually it works. Decorate the "inlined" function with `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]`.

Comment: @Lamar - Performance - the array could be pretty big and this code has to be run almost every other frame in a mobile game.

Comment: @Gusman - Yes, I've come across that, but since it's not guaranteed, that would be my last option.

Comment: Sounds like you don't want to pass too many parameters. Create an type to hold intermediate values as public fields/properties and then just call methods without parameters (or with reduced number). An advantage of such approach is an easy way to reset everything by creating a new object, as well as access to some of the values during/after calculation (e.g. for debugging purposes).

Comment: @BlueSilver I don't think that's your last option but your only option.

Comment: Why do you have to scan the array twice in this manner? Isn't there anything to make it possible to do in 1 go?

Comment: The C# compiler will usually inline short methods, otherwise use the suggestions from the other comments. Have you tested your app & found a performance bottleneck in this code? Or are you preemptively optimising? Because if you really think you need these kinds of performance gains, you should not be writing this in a managed interpreted langauge like C# in the first place. .Net trades developer productivity for low level performance. That trade-off suits the majority of applications in the world, including web sites that scale to billions of operations a day. Otherwise you need C or C++

Comment: @AshleyPillay I'm using Unity, so I am stuck with C#. I haven't yet moved the code into a separate function, and hence haven't measured the impact - I will do that. I was just wondering if there was a simple alternative that I had missed.

Comment: OK I get you @BlueSilver. My suggestion is to not use compiler hints until you first benchmark & notice a problem. They may inline the method, but the guys who wrote the C# compiler know how to optimise it far better than you or I. If they decide not to inline, it's probably for a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the AggressiveInlining option on methods

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
void Method2()
{
    // ... Aggressive inlining.
}
```

Source: https://www.dotnetperls.com/aggressiveinlining

Comment: Yes I've seen this, but it is just a hint to the compiler. There is no guarantee that it will be inlined.

Comment: True, you could do some performance measurement to see if the JIT compiler will honor the request.

Comment: This article basically says that what this flag will do is ognore the size of the method when inlining https://dzone.com/articles/aggressive-inlining-clr-45-jit

Comment: @Vanna I agree with you that there is a potential to make things slower if you inline. But the only way to know for sure is to measure.